# How can we make caption the appear inside of the fbox?

Tags: floats, minipage, fbox

I would like a figure caption to appear inside of the same framed box other figure elements appear inside of. Below we have several nested environments.
The ordering of the nesting is: `figure` > `fbox` > `minipage`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}    
\begin{document}  


\begin{figure}[htpb] 
    \centering
    \fbox{
        \begin{minipage}{4 cm}
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{solution_count_satisfiability}
        \end{minipage}
    }% end fbox
    \caption{CAPTION TEXT}
\end{figure}    

\end{document}
```

However, in the output document, the caption renders outside of the `fbox`. How can we make the caption render inside of the `fbox`? It seems like the `\caption` statement must be at the top-level inside of the figure. We cannot nest the `\caption` statement inside something else nested within the figure.

```
\begin{figure} % OKAY
    \begin{thing1}
        strawberries
    \end{thing1}

    \begin{thing1}
        kiwis
    \end{thing1}

    \caption{C}

\end{figure}

\begin{figure} % NOT OKAY
    \begin{thing1}
        \caption{C} % caption is too deeply nested
    \end{thing1}
    \begin{thing2}
        kiwis
    \end{thing2}        
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 3):

`\caption` is a vertical mode construct, it should be inside the `minipage`, also you probably do not want the spaces either side of the minipage in the box, so `\fbox{\begin{minipage}` not `\fbox{ \begin{minipage}`